# WIX - Same version MsiPackage being uninstalled during bundle upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I increased the version of my boostrapper for an upgrade. When I try to install the newer version of the boostraper, any of my custom MsiPackages in the boostrapper that are already installed with the same version numbers get uninstalled. It should not take any action since it is already installed.

I am seeing this in the log but don't know what the second line means.

```
[1EDC:0810][2017-07-13T12:26:06]i052: Condition 'NOT COTSENDERVERSION OR (COTSENDERVERSION < v2.0.0.440)' evaluates to false.
[1EDC:0810][2017-07-13T12:26:06]w208: Plan disabled rollback for package: CotSenderInstaller.msi, due to incomplete cache: None, original rollback action: Install
```

Which leads to it being uninstalled

```
[1EDC:0810][2017-07-13T12:26:06]i201: Planned package: CotSenderInstaller.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
```

Here is the MsiPackage element

```
 <PackageGroup Id="CotSender">
      <MsiPackage
           Cache="yes"
           Compressed="yes"
           Vital="yes"
           Visible="yes"
           ForcePerMachine ="yes"
           SourceFile="$(var.CotSenderInstaller.TargetPath)"
           InstallCondition="NOT COTSENDERVERSION OR (COTSENDERVERSION &lt; $(custom.GetFileVersion($(var.CotSenderInstaller.TargetPath))))"
      />
 </PackageGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `InstallCondition` attribute. Burn already handles this scenario.

Comment: I guess if the InstallCondition returns false then it will uninstall it.